# How to get ChangeDetectorRef of child components in Angular (2+)?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

Given this component structure:

```
<slider>
    <slide></slide>
    <slide></slide>
    <slide></slide>
    <slide></slide>
</slider>
```

Is it possible in `Slider` to get `ChangeDetectorRef` of all `Slide`'s?

---

I'd like to detach/reattach change detector on slides based on their visibility. For the sake of question, lets assume `Slide` component is a black box, otherwise it would be quite simple to implement with `@Input() isDetached: boolean`.

Angular 2+

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bs2bd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: `lets assume Slide component is a black box` https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wt617u?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: nice trick with directive, thanks :)

Comment: @yurzui awesome trick! Still handy.